# MySql Foreign key primary key not matching

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a trouble linking all the foreign keys with the primary keys. I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Patients 
        (pid        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         name       VARCHAR(25),
         address        VARCHAR(30),
         telephone  VARCHAR(10),
         care_centre_id INT,
CONSTRAINT Patients_PK PRIMARY KEY (pid));

CREATE TABLE Care_centres 
        (cid        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         name       VARCHAR(25),
         location       VARCHAR(30),
         nurse_charge_id    INT,
CONSTRAINT Care_centres_PK PRIMARY KEY (cid));

ALTER TABLE Patients ADD FOREIGN KEY (care_centre_id) REFERENCES Care_centres(cid);
```

cid is a primary key of Care_centres table, and care_cente_id is the foreign key of Patients table. Whenever I run the query table(MySql) it shows NULL values in foreign key. How can I index the correspondence of foreign key with primary key, it is Ok to randomly assigned values to foreign key.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Patients;
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+----------------+
| pid | name   | address        | telephone  | care_centre_id |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|   1 | Joe    | 8 Walker Road  | 7800921111 |           NULL |
|   2 | Jose   | 10 Runner Road | 7800922222 |           NULL |
|   3 | Joseph | 12 Jogger Road | 7800923333 |           NULL |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+----------------+
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just because you specified an FK doesn't mean mysql can magically fill in those values for you. Since you allow `care_center_id` to be null, mysql doesn't require there to be a matching parent record in `care_centers`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert rows into the Patients table, you need to specify the care_centre_id column to create the association between that patient and the specified care centre.  Otherwise the database has no way of knowing which patient belongs to which care centre.

So, for example, let's say you have care centres like this:

```
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+
| cid | name   | location       | nurse_charge_id |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+
|   1 | centre1| someplace      | 1              |
|   2 | centre2| someplace else | 1              |
```

You could, for example, assign Joe and Jose to care centre 1 and Joseph to care centr 2

```
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+----------------+
| pid | name   | address        | telephone  | care_centre_id |
+-----+--------+----------------+------------+----------------+
|   1 | Joe    | 8 Walker Road  | 7800921111 |           1    |
|   2 | Jose   | 10 Runner Road | 7800922222 |           1    |
|   3 | Joseph | 12 Jogger Road | 7800923333 |           2    |
```

You would do this during your initial insert of the patient, or on a subsequent update.